# Using fetch api in html

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I have an easy problem regarding the use of `fetch` in html files.

I've created an API in AWS Api Gateway that has a simple GET method: the GET method returs a json.

Now, if i access directly or using [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to the link of my method it works correctly, but when i try to use `fetch` something wrong happens and i see no results.

I search on the internet because i don't know neither javascript nor html, but i can't find how make it works correctly.
For example what i'm trying to do in the code that follows is to put the json taken via GET into a label.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>test.html</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <dl>
         <dt>Page 1</dt>
         <dd>Go to <a href="https://xxx.execute-api.eu-central- 
   1.amazonaws.com/prod/getcustomerdetailsbyemail/">link</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <p> <input name="Button" value="Click me" onclick="buttonClick()" type="button">&nbsp;<input
         name="Button2" value="Click me 2" formmethod="get" onclick="buttonClick2()" type="button">
      </p>
      <p> <input id="myText" name="Message" value="Insert text" type="text"></p>
      <label for="myText" id="mylabel"></label>
      <div id="myData"> </div>
      <dl>
      </dl>
      <dl>
      </dl>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function buttonClick(){
            alert(document.getElementById("myText").value);
         }
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function buttonClick2(){
          fetch("https://xxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/getcustomerdetailsbyemail")
           .then(response => {
               document.getElementById("mylabel").value = response.json();
           })
           .catch(error => {
               alert("Nope");
           });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can i put the json returned by the get call into a label?

I have another question: if i put  `console.log("message")` in a script in an html file, what should i expect to happen when the script is run? (Spoiler: nothing happens, why?)

I apologize if I am ignoring something crucial, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Change this line - `document.getElementById("mylabel").textContent = response.json();` HTML labels dont have a `value` property, but HTML input does

Comment: consider parsing your json after resolving it, do not immediately push it to the node value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `response.json()` yields a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you'll need to wait for that to resolve and consume the result:

```
function buttonClick2(){
  fetch("https://your-url.com")
   .then(response => response.json()) // <-- important line
   .then(response => {
       // changed .value to .innerHTML but you can handle it as you wish
       document.getElementById("mylabel").innerHTML = response;
   })
   .catch(error => {
       alert("Nope");
   });
}
```

Here you can check the documentation for [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) with examples

Comment: It works, you are the best! Thank you, thank you very much.